# How to store lat and longitude values in multi-dim array iOS Google Maps app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

This method runs everytime the user taps.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
[rightArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude]];
[rightArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude]];
```

My rightArray now contains all the lat and longitude values in order, but how could I store them in a multi-dimensional array, broken up by values of 2? So (10,20;30,20;10,90).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to add array in rightArray.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSArray *array = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude]];
    [rightArray addObject:array];
}
```

Also instead of nested array you can create array of `NSDictionary`.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{"lat":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude], 
                           "long":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude]};
    [rightArray addObject:dictionary];
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank u sir

Comment: @konyv12 Welcome mate, check once edited answer also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make standard multidimensional NSArray like in C. But you have few alternatives you can do this. All 'Objective-C ways' are rather clunky and inelegant if you ask me. For example:

1. Store CLLocationCoordinate2D in NSData like so:

   ```
   [NSData dataWithBytes:&coordinate length:sizeof(coordinate)]];
   ```
2. Store NSNumbers from CLLocationCoordinate2D as either NSArray or NSDictionary.
3. Create a separate class that stores CLLocationCoordinate2D as public property and store that in NSArray - de facto standard way to do things like this in Objective-C
4. Rename the file to .mm and use `std::vector<CLLocationCoordinate2D>` instead of NSArray - my preferred solution
5. Just use straight up C way of making CLLocationCoordinate2D array. But you will need to manage memory allocation, reallocation on deletion yourself.